# Custom product module

Tags: catalog, module

How i can make custom module and then add products in custom module? i want add new section in backend and then work with this section (section catalog also should work)

Thanks

Comment: you have to create custom magento grid using extension

Comment: extension free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much clear what you want to do. I'm assuming that you want to create an admin panel module. The below links may helpful.

http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/08/create-your-first-adminbackend-module.html

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/13/tutorial-create-admin-manageable-magento-entity-brands/

Comment: sorry for my bad english, but i not know how i can create product in my custom module, also i don't know how text area in backend save and show in frontend